# Getting checkbox value/name shows empty or undefined alert

Tags: php, javascript

This is the php chunk of code...

```
echo "<td> 
          <input type='checkbox' value='online_$row[0]' " .                                             
          $checked[$row[$i]]. " onchange='background()'/>                                   
      </td>";
```

and here is the very simple javascript code...

```
function background()
{
    alert(this.value); 
}
```

How can I get that checkboxe's name using the this keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 echo "<td> 
      <input type='checkbox' value='online_$row[0]' " .                                             
      $checked[$row[$i]]. " onchange='background(this)'/>                                   
  </td>";

function background(ele)
{
alert(ele.value); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is the input inside the `onclick` function … but that function calls `background` without any context, so it gets the default context of `window` so inside that function `this` is `window`

Bind the `background` function to the input element directly instead of using the `onclick` attribute to create a new function.

```
refToInput.addEventListener('change', background);
```

See [MDN for more reading on addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) including notes on browser compatibility.

Comment: I was reading this...http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html maybe I misunderstood? I thought that when calling a function from an element "this" would refer to that element.

Comment: @DeusDeceit — Yes, but as the answer says, you are calling `onclick` from the element, and you are calling `background` from the `onclick` function.

Answer (score 1):

In the JS function you must pass an object, so "this" will be actually defined.
For example, you could use:

```
function background(elem)
{
    alert(elem.value); 
}
```

Once the function does not have any argument, "this" is not defined and therefore the function does not run as excepted.